# web interface form for querying database using linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I've got a database with a stack load of data in it.
I'd like to make a web interface which will allow the user to put in an LINQ query, which will return results in a table.

How do I limit it to allow selection only? (I'm thinking the best way is to create another database user with select permissions only)

Anything else I should be aware of, or any other ideas?

Comment: Are you asking how to make it read only?

Answer (score 1):

Are you just trying to expose your database as a webservice?  I would strongly reccomend [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106).

This basically allows for people to query your data using a rest interface.  There is also a client side linq api, that converts link statements to rest.  There is plenty of build in security that can facilitate allowing people to only query your data, and not change it.

Comment: I guess my question is more about dynamically compiling queries that a user types into a webpage. WCF Data services is cool, but I want the user to be able to custom query the database.

Comment: They can custom query the database?  The client data service API can do about 75% of what LINQ to Entities can do.